# Problems connecting to services

Tags: swisscomdev

I followed the docs in order to get access to my ELK Service:

```
cf login
```

And selecting appropriate org and space

```
cf create-service-key <service-instance-name> mykey
```

And then

```
cf service-key <service-instance-name> mykey
```

All of which works so far. However, accessing the kibana URL fails

```
cf service-connector 9000 http://xmnlzu2mkmsn05ll.service.consul:56063
```

with the following error

FAILED
Value for remote host and remote port is not valid.

There is no firewall blocking rule for this.

Edit: There is also no proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of the service connector expects the hostname:port without protocol prefix. Could you try:

`cf service-connector 9000 xmnlzu2mkmsn05ll.service.consul:56063`

That should work as expected.

(Disclaimer: I work for Swisscom)

Comment: Yes thanks. That worked perfectly. I was copy-pasting the kibana Url form the service key, and the http:// came along